# Zap scan is not running SOAP injection test

Tags: docker, soap, zap

I am passing the 90019 scanner, for SOAP injection, into a zap script, but it is not running it, while it does run other rules, such as OS Command Injection, and SSI Server Side. I am running zap from a docker container and I noticed watching the output that these other rules correspond to a particular zap plugin. So, I am guessing I am missing a SOAP plugin in my environment and my question is: how can I install a plugin in Docker that corresponds to scanner 90019 to make sure that the script that runs zap scan checks for this rule? Many thanks. If there's something else that I am missing or more info is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SOAP Scanner is included in this add-on: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/wiki/HelpAddonsSoapSoap
This is included in the weekly docker image but not in the stable one.

You can install it when you start ZAP in the docker container by adding the parameters:

> -addoninstall soap

You can also install add-ons using the ZAP API, but thats only worth doing if you are already using the API.

Comment: Bennets Passing the parameter into the Dockerfile did not help. To do it with the API, is using zap.autoupdate.install_addon("90019") in python API sufficient or do I need to do something else? Thanks

Comment: Used the weekly image and it worked - thanks for all the help.